# Check if column exists before executing Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query:

```
 SELECT Table_Name   AS Table_Name,
        'select  count(*) from '
        || Table_Name
        || 'where language!=0' AS Query
   FROM All_Tables
  WHERE Owner = 'databaseName'
    AND ( Table_Name LIKE 'HH%'
     OR Table_Name LIKE 'TT%' )
```

however, not all tables have column `language`. How to check whetther such column exists and if it exists then check for `language` value?

Comment: you can modify your existing query using EXISTS clause.. check out my answer below ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your existing query like this:

```
SELECT table_name AS Table_name,
       'select  count(*) from ' || table_name || ' where language!=0' as query
  FROM all_tables t
 WHERE t.owner = 'databaseName' 
   AND (t.table_name LIKE 'HH%' 
        OR t.table_name LIKE 'TT%')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM all_tab_columns c 
                WHERE c.table_name = t.table_name
                  AND c.owner = t.owner
                  AND UPPER(c.column_name) = 'LANGUAGE')
```

Let me know if it helps.

Thanks
Idrees

Comment: Thank you! is it worked for getting only these tables that have language. Is it possible to join these that don't have that column with different query?

Comment: Yes .. u can add similar query in the UNION clause with the other condition

Comment: like ..     `SELECT condition_1 UNION SELECT condition_2`

Answer (score 4):

Column names are stored in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`; join it with `USER_TABLES` via `TABLE_NAME` column, e.g.

```
select *
from user_tables t join user_tab_columns c on t.table_name = c.table_name
```

As you know the *table name*, you should be able to check whether certain column exists or not.

If you use `ALL_TABLES` / `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, include the `OWNER` value as well.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a column exists within a particular table use:

```
  SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tab_columns 
  WHERE UPPER(column_name) = UPPER(<your column _name>) and 
  TABLE_NAME=upper(<your table_name>);
```